# Arduino and XBee Series1

Tags: xbee

I have actually reap 3 numerical values ​​(3 sensors) from a remote XBee module and then manipulate these 3 signal with an Arduino card attached to another XBee module. To do this, I chose to use the IO line passing because it proved the easiest. My problem is this: for the XBee transmitter, I set:

```
ATID 3001 
ATDL 2
ATMY 1 
ATIU 1 / / to activate the IO option 
ATD0 3 / / where is plugged a pushbutton 
ATD1 3 / / where is plugged another pushbutton
ATD2 3 / / where is plugged proximity sensor (presence)
```

For the XBee receiver (the one connected with the arduino board):

```
ATID 3001 ATDL 1 ATMY 2 ATIA 1
ATD0 4 
ATD1 4 
ATD2 4
```

Where I'm stuck is on the Arduino programming. Which command is used to determine the change of state of xbee remote? because I want to know if the states of the sensors on input are high or low.

Comment: possible duplicate of [communication xbee and arduino](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3101/communication-xbee-and-arduino)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways this could be tackled:

1. physically through connections between the xbee and arduino and read the xbee pins directly (I've never done this, and it comes down to your shield supporting it). Each of the desired output pins of the receiving xbee would be tied to a GPIO pin of the arduino. Alternatively,
2. serially using `AT` commands via the serial connection.

I have never worked with series one, but essentially:

1. setup a serial connection to your arduino
2. send the desired `AT` command requesting the pins value
3. read the serial port response

Make sure to read the manual for the series 1 xbees for the right `AT` commands and in how to interpret the results. [Register at digi](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-series1-module) and download the datasheet.

Also, just realise reading the xbee data is going to be different depending on how you have the xbee setup, ie `API` vs `AT` mode.

Here is someone who has done some work with series 1: http://www.johnhenryshammer.com/WOW2/pagesHowTo/xbeeSeries1.php#index

I'll leave the actual implementation to you since this sounds a little like a homework assignment. Give it a go using the second method above and see how you go. Then post back here (ie update the question) including source code and exact layout (schematic preferred) and we'll see where we can help you from there.

Hint: google such terms as: "read data pins xbee arduino" (without the quotes).